# How can I get my spawners to work when they are far away?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I am playing a custom map and I have 2 mob spawners in which I have set up traps for. These traps lead to the same place, however both spawners are considerably far away from each other and therefore only one spawns at a time (when I am near).

I was wondering if there was some sort of way to "mimic" a player position without a player actually being there. What I would usually do is start up another computer and simply open it to LAN and have another account be somewhere next to the spawner, however I was wondering if there was a way to not have to do this? Is this possible? Are there any mods that allow this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you're up for modding, then I guess you're up for just editing the map!

You can adjust the [Mob Spawner TileEntity Field](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#MobSpawner) for `RequiredPlayerRange` to something higher. This can be done with an [MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/) filter, there are a few of [Texelelf's Filters](http://elemanser.com/filters.html) that could do the job.

Comment: Thankyou :). I used the Unified Spawner Filter by Texeleif for people wondering.

Comment: to add to this answer, spawners have a "box" around them for detection. Using editors you can move this box, and change its size (data is stored in nbt tags).

Comment: @legacy I don't think that's correct. It's not a box, it's a radius that defines a sphere.

Comment: There is no need for MCEdit any more. Tile entity fields can be set using `/setblock` or `/blockdata` commands.

Answer (score 3):

You really don't need any mods or any external program to do this! Do it straight from vanilla Minecraft via the `/setblock` command. Simply add the tag `RequiredPlayerRange` followed by the amount of blocks, and the command should look something like this:

```
/setblock (x) (y) (z) minecraft:mob_spawner 0 replace {RequiredPlayerRange:(blocks)}
```

More info can be found watching Dragnoz's video here:

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

To edit the spawn distance of mob spawner in 1.13 and above the command will be:

```
/data merge block (x) (y) (z) {RequiredPlayerRange: (amount)}
```