# How can I keep a monster spawner spawning whilst I'm away?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know that Minecraft spawn cages only spawn when you are near them, and the mob can spawn there naturally - but is there a way to keep them spawning? I need the spawner to work when I am away.

Comment: I recently asked a question about this: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124124/how-can-i-get-my-spawners-to-work-when-they-are-far-away

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Without mods or editing the world using external tools, there is no way to keep a spawner active by yourself.

1. You could buy a second copy of Minecraft or have someone else join your world and stand next to your spawner.
2. By editing the world you can change the [`RequiredPlayerRange`](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Chunk_format#Tile_Entity_Format) of the spawner so that it activates from a farther distance. This would generally be considered cheating for a survival world.

What I would recommend is to find ways to make better use of your time standing next to the spawner, by building things to work on there — equipment for crafting, potion brewing, etc. I've built a pool for fishing near one of my spawners, since that's something that also takes lots of time but also requires interaction. If you've got a particularly good setup like two spawners in the same area, maybe even build your base around them.

Comment: I like the RequiredPlayerRange one!!!! how do I do that??? is there an mcedit filter you could show me? I heard one exists...

Comment: Don't know anything about available tools, sorry.