# How do I change Tile Entities?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I heard if you change something called `RequiredPlayerRange` to a high number on a spawner, it will be able to spawn even from a distance. I don't know to change [Tile Entities](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tile_entity) though. How exactly do I change that?

Comment: Honestly, I don't think this should stand as a separate question from your other question. You *could* change it to ask generically how to edit Tile Entities, but otherwise, in my opinion it's just an offshoot from the other question that doesn't really hold terribly well on it's own.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I keep a monster spawner spawning whilst I'm away?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/129425/how-can-i-keep-a-monster-spawner-spawning-whilst-im-away)

Comment: This should be a comment on the other question's answer asking for a better explanation.

Comment: This and the other question are duplicates of [How can I get my spawners to work when they are far away?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/124124/how-can-i-get-my-spawners-to-work-when-they-are-far-away), which fully answers both questions.

Comment: @Schism Any reason you linked to a question that is also marked as a duplicate?

Comment: @Batophobia When I marked this as a possible duplicate 21 hours ago, the other question, marked as a duplicate 9 hours ago, was still open.

Comment: This is not a dupe.  Changing tile entities can apply to more than just spawners.  Answers on this question have _applications_ on the proposed dupe question, but the scopes are different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to edit the NBTData of the spawner. Sethbling has **[this filter](http://sethbling.com/downloads/mcedit-filters/setspawnerproperties/)** which can be downloaded onto **[MCEdit](http://www.mcedit.net/)** to change most spawner properties.

If you are not familiar with MCEdit or want a way to do it in game I would recommend **[this mod](http://www.minecraftforum.net/topic/1558668-162forgesspsmp-in-game-nbtedit-edit-mob-spawners-attributes-in-game/)**. You will need to look at the spawner, type /nbtedit, and then change RequiredPlayerRange.

Comment: I second the nbtedit mod. I also suggest you add some sort of keybind mod, as trying to focus your cursor on a mob and then having it walk away before you type /nbtedit is annoying.

Comment: the mcedit filter is what I tried first, and it worked. the mod? nbtedit? i use the external one. Thanks!